# Flip Carousel when I click on the arrow left/right, I want the whole carousel to flip horizontally showing its back side

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I don't know how to use jquery to make this active, or if I should use Jquery to begin with. When I click on the left arrow, I want the image in the carousel to flip to the other side, How do you suggest I do that?

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle ? By flipping to you mean this kind of trick https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/

Comment: Take a look [Here](http://wowslider.com/es/bootstrap-carousel-demo.html#)

Comment: Okay, in this case can you please create a jsfiddle with style needed ? It will be easier for us to edit this jsfiddle to make it works.

Comment: Did you try to download the plugin to shape it as you want ?